# why can't use ternary operator with different types when boost variable can hold multiple types?

Tags: c++, boost

I have something like below, but unable to compile it. I don't get it why I can't have different type when my variable can hold different types?

My code:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, std::string> MultiType;

int main() {
    int a = 1;
    std::string b = "b";
    bool c = true;
    MultiType d = c ? a : b;
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

> Error C2446   ':': no conversion from 'std::string' to 'int'

Comment: lesson to be learned: The conditional operator is not a drop in replacement for a `if-else`. Don't use it merely to save some typing

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I don’t think that’s a good lesson to learn here. In a language with dynamic typing and a ternary operator, it would clearly be a better approach than a conditional statement. The shape of the operation — selecting between two values — is the bailiwick of conditional expressions, not conditional statements. The only lesson to learn here is a specific one about the collision between a statically typed language and a library which wants to be a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Put it this way: if `b` were an `int`, would you still criticize the OP for using a conditional expression?

Comment: @Sneftel Its a lesson specific to C++. Other languages work differently

Comment: @Sneftel I didnt critize OP. If `b` were an `int` then using the ternary would be ok, because then both operands are of same type. One has to be aware of how the conditional operator works and that it isnt the right replacment for all `if-else` that assign a value, that doesnt imply that it is always the wrong tool

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression `c ? a : b` has to have a type. There is no common type between `std::string` and `int`, so that expression is invalid.

There is a common type between `std::string` and `MultiType`, and between `int` and `MultiType`, so `c ? MultiType{ a } : b` is a valid expression, as is `c ? a : MultiType{ b }`